# AuthenticationState cascading value always null for the razor pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

There is a Razor component (UserProfile.razor) which is trying to get the logged in user's info using the AuthenticationState CascadingParameter. When using this (UserProfile.razor) in any Blazor page (i.e. UserPage.razor) it returns the user's info. But when the same component (UserProfile.razor) is used in any Razor page (i.e. Index.cshtml) the _authState get always null.

Is there any way to get it fix?

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@using static MyApp.Components.UserProfile;
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Index;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div>
            <h2 class="mb-3">Hello, @Model.FriendlyUserName!</h2>
            <div class="my-3">
                <label class="form-label">Your username is</label>
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Please choose your username." disabled />
            </div>
            <p>
                You cannot change that. However, you can update your
                other personal information on the right.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <component type="typeof(Components.UserProfile)"
                   render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

    public IndexModel(
        UserManager<User> userManager,
        SignInManager<User> signInManager)
    {
      _userManager = userManager;
      _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public User _user { get; set; } = null!;

    public string FriendlyUserName
    {
      get
      {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_user.FirstName))
        {
          if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_user.LastName))
          {
            return $"{_user.FirstName} {_user.LastName}";
          }
          else
          {
            return _user.FirstName;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          return _user.UserName;
        }
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    public string Username { get; set; }
    //public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //public string LastName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    public class InputModel
    {
      /// <summary>
      ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
      ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
      /// </summary>

      [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.Text)]
      [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.Text)]
      [Display(Name = "LastName")]
      public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    private async Task LoadAsync(User user)
    {
      var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
      Username = userName;
      Input = new InputModel
      {
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName
      };
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
      _user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
      if (_user == null)
      {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
      }

      await LoadAsync(_user);
      return Page();
    }
  }
}
```

**UserProfile.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
@using MyApp.Pages;

<EditForm Model="@Input" OnValidSubmit="OnSubmit">
    <h2>User Details</h2>
</EditForm>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Task<AuthenticationState>? _authState { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (_authState is not null) //_authState is always null when this component is used in razor page i.e. Index.cshtml
        {
            var authenticationState = await _authState;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters) states:

> Cascading values and parameters provide a convenient way to flow data down a component hierarchy from an ancestor component to any number of descendant components.

This means that data from the Blazor page that instantiates the component is forwarded to the component.

Razor pages aren't Blazor. Hence no data is forwarded from the Razor page to the Blazor page. It's a different (older) technology. Razor pages/views have [their own conventions for authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization).

Putting Blazor components in razor pages is not a good idea, as you lose the Blazor functionality. The main `Index.cshtml` is the exception, as that starts the Blazor app. However, no data is forwarded at that time.
With A LOT of effort you could probably make it to work, but then you're re-engineering Blazor. And it's very hacky.

If there is no base Blazor component, i.e. you want direct access to the `AuthenticationState`, you need to inject `AuthenticationStateProvider` in your blazor component instead of using this Cascading parameter. See the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/).

```cs
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

...

var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider
    .GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
```

Stuff like this doesn't really need to be forwarded anyhow: so use DI.